# reading file, no output in the console (intellij)

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, following a tutorial to read files. The code is supposed to print line by line from the text file, Not seeing any output in IntelliJ Console.

I've tried other code examples and can see the output of the program but just this file module is not showing any.

```
import scala.io.Source._

object readfile extends App {

    println("hello")

    val filename = "src/rainbow.txt"
    for(line <- fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
        println(line)
    }

    println(filename)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be working in an Intellij worksheet (or scratch pad, as they now call it). If so then the problem is that your `object` extends `App`, which wraps your object's code in a hidden `main()` method.

There are three easy ways to execute the code and see output.

1 - Invoke `main()` *after* the definition of the `readfile` object.

```
readfile.main(Array())
```

2 - Take out the `extends App` and then invoke (reference) `readfile` after its definition.

3 - Take out the `object` wrapper altogether and let Intellij run the code directly.

```
import scala.io.Source._

println("hello")

val filename = "src/rainbow.txt"
for(line <- fromFile(filename).getLines()) {
  println(line)
}
println(filename)
```

Comment: All 3 approaches work with errors at least. Thanks. Q1. is this hidden main like `public static void main in java?` Q2. #1 and #2 and #3 throws `java.io.FileNotFoundException` because of the path error, I tried both `rainbow.txt` and `src/rainbow.txt`

Comment: A1. Yes. A2. The current working directory for IntelliJ's scratch pad is the directory from which IntelliJ was launched. (In my case it's `$HOME`.) You could also try the absolute path to the input file.

Comment: I see. something aside if you don't mind answering, I assume `object` creates instance from my example and `class` is the blueprint in scala. so if that's true then in context of A1, `public static void main` is a static method to be called without creating an object. Otherwise please enlighten me.

Comment: Scala doesn't have `static`. What it has is `object`s which can be thought of as a `class` with a guaranteed singleton instance. Like Java, the compiled bytecode needs an entry or starting point. In Scala that is the `main()` method in an `object` and it is invoked when the operating system loads and executes the program. For more details do some research/reading. This is a bit beyond the realm of SO comments.